# Custom UITableViewRowAnimation or duration

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I have an app where the user can drag `UITableViewCells` from one `TableView` to another. I do this by rendering a "dummy" cell on top of the UITableViewCell that the user touches, and disable the "real" cell. I then insert a new row in the destination `UITableView`, after I have animated the dummy cell, to the position where the new cell will be inserted. This works as i want it to. But the other way around, causes me a lot of issues.

When a cell from the destination UITableView I double tapped, the cell should animate back to the source UITableView where it initially was dragged from. The problem is that I cannot remove the cell from the destination `UITableView` fast enough.

I want it to disappear instantly, so that when I render a dummy cell on top of it, I won't see an 2 different animations of the same cell. (the one where the dummy cell moves to the source `UITableView`, and the one where the actual cell is removed from the destination `UITableView`).

A `reloadData` on the `UITableView` is not good enough, because I still want the remaining cells to pull together on the now empty space, with an animation.

So, can I somehow create a custom animation, or set the duration of `UITableViewRowAnimation` to zero? `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` does not do anything for me.

Oh, and it might be important to mention that the app is not going on App Store, so I don't care if iI have to do something that Apple will not approve of.

Comment: How about covering the cell that is about to disappear with a view that looks like the table view's background before the animation? That way, the dummy cell would appear to move from an empty space.

Comment: What methods are you currently using and are there some methods that you are using that you must use for your animation to take effect?

Comment: i currently use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle, that is the one i guess i have to use.

Covering the cell with a view that has the same look as the background might actually be the way to go. But then again, the background is not a solid color, and can change a lot, so i would prefer to just override the animation.