# UITableViewRowAnimation custom animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I know that there are the default `UITableViewRowAnimation` options, but is there a way to create my own animation?  If so, are their tutorials on this?

I want my cells to zoom toward the user, then fly off screen.

I can't seem to find much about this...

Comment: possible duplicate: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382936/custom-uitableviewrowanimation-or-duration>

Comment: Maybe a duplicate, but still need to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is in willDisplayCell, you have access to UIView/CAAnimation API's there. Example:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    //1. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    cell.alpha = 0;
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.85, 0.85);

    //2. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"scale" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    cell.alpha = 1;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This is a simple 'scale', shadow, and alpha-in applied to the cell. As the table scrolls the cells scale in and become opaque. You can really do anything you want in here.